# Using java class that imports external jarfiles inside C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have successfully implemented the JNI inside c++ code. The problem occurs when I import external jar file called xeger.jar and use its function in the java code. The code on the java file runs while using ecllipse to run it even when I use external library. But when I call it using JNI inside the c++ code, then it doesnot return the value as expected.

I have the following java class

```
package cversion.xeger.implementation;

import nl.flotsam.xeger.Xeger;

public class StringGenerator {

    public static int giveMeNumber(int x) {
        int y = 33;
        String regex = "[1-9]\\|[1-9][0-9]{1,5}\\|1000000";
        Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
        String result = generator.generate();
        System.out.println("Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + result);
        return y;
    }
}
```

My c++ code is as follow :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
      JavaVMOption options[1];
      JNIEnv *env;
      JavaVM *jvm;
      JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
      long status;
      jclass cls;
      jmethodID mid;
      jint square;
      jboolean answer;

   // options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>("-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server");
   options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>("-Djava.class.path=/home/aaa/eclipse-workspace/xeger/target/classes:/home/aaa/Downloads/automaton-1.12/dist/automation.jar:/home/aaa/Downloads/dxeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
   // options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>("-Djava.class.path=/home/aaa/Desktop/classpath-try/");
   // options[0].optionString =  const_cast<char *>("-Djava -cp /home/aaa/Desktop/Untitled.jar");
   memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.options = options;
   status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); //If JVM creation is successful then status value is zero
   std::cout<<"Status of JNI creation is : "<<status<<std::endl;

   if (status != JNI_OK)
   {
     std::cout<<"JNI creation Failed : "<<std::endl;
     return 1;
   }
   std::cout<<"JNI creation Passed : "<<std::endl;
   cls = env->FindClass("cversion/xeger/implementation/StringGenerator");  // If the class cannot be found, cls will be zero.
   std::cout<<"The class of cls is : "<<typeid(cls).name()<<std::endl;
   // cls = env->FindClass("Sample2"); 
   std::cout<<"The value of cls is : "<<cls<<std::endl;
     if(cls !=0)
     {  
        mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "giveMeNumber", "(I)I");
        std::cout<<"The value of mid is : "<<mid<<std::endl; 
         if(mid !=0)
         {  square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 25);
            std::cout<<"The value of square is "<<square<<std::endl;
            printf("Result of implementation : %d\n", square);
         }
     }
     jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run the c++ file then the line:

```
printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
```

prints 0. It was supposed to print 33.

Now if I remove the following code from the java file then it prints 33.

```
String regex = "[1-9]\\|[1-9][0-9]{1,5}\\|1000000";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
System.out.println("Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly fine for me:

```
lib/main
Status of JNI creation is : 0
JNI creation Passed :
The class of cls is : P7_jclass
The value of cls is : 0x7f9b26c0d0b0
The value of mid is : 0x7f9b26c28230
Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!3|27654|1000000
The value of square is 33
Result of implementation : 33
```

Do following in your code:

```
int y = 33;
try {
  String regex = "[1-9]\\|[1-9][0-9]{1,5}\\|1000000";
  Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
  String result = generator.generate();
  System.out.println("Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + result);
} catch(Throwable ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
return y;
```

and error will reveal itself ;)

I bet you will get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dk/brics/automaton/RegExp
    at nl.flotsam.xeger.Xeger.<init>(Xeger.java:45)
```

Take a look here, for fully reproducible use-case:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── Makefile.common
├── c
│   └── main.cc
├── jar
│   ├── automaton.jar
│   └── xeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
├── java
│   └── simple
│       └── JavaCode.java
├── lib
└── target
```

You need main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "jni.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
  JavaVMOption options[1];
  JNIEnv *env;
  JavaVM *jvm;
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

  options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>("-Djava.class.path=./target:./jar/xeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:./jar/automaton.jar");
  memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;

  long status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

  std::cout << "Status of JNI creation is : "
            << status
            << std::endl;

  if( status != JNI_OK ) {
    std::cout << "JNI creation Failed : "
              << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "JNI creation Passed : "
            << std::endl;

  jclass cls = env->FindClass("simple/JavaCode");

  std::cout << "The class of cls is : "
            << typeid(cls).name()
            << std::endl
            << "The value of cls is : "
            << cls
            << std::endl;

  if( cls != 0 ) {
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "giveMeNumber", "(I)I");

    std::cout << "The value of mid is : "
              << mid
              << std::endl;

    if( mid != 0 ) {
      jint square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 25);

      std::cout << "The value of square is "
                << square
                << std::endl;

      printf("Result of implementation : %d\n", square);
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
  jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
  return 0;
}
```

and Java code

```
package simple;

import nl.flotsam.xeger.Xeger;

public class JavaCode {

    public static int giveMeNumber(int x) {
        int y = 33;
        try {
          String regex = "[1-9]\\|[1-9][0-9]{1,5}\\|1000000";
          Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
          String result = generator.generate();
          System.out.println("Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + result);
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

**1. LLVM based setup**

I use make to build code as I compile both Java and native code at the same time. So, you need Makefile.common

```
ARCH=$(shell uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
ifeq ($(ARCH),darwin)
  EXT=dylib
else
  EXT=so
endif
```

and `Makefile`. Be careful with tabs !! Make requires tab to be the first character at each line of target.

```
include ./Makefile.common

ifeq ($(ARCH),darwin)
CC=llvm-g++
MAC_OS_FLAGS=-rpath ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -dynamic -arch x86_64 -lSystem
else
CC=g++
MAC_OS_FLAGS=
endif

all: lib/main target/simple/JavaCode.class

target/simple/JavaCode.class: java/simple/JavaCode.java
    $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac -cp ./jar/xeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -d target $<

lib/main.o: c/main.cc
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/$(ARCH)

lib/main: lib/main.o
    llvm-g++ -v -o $@ -L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server/ -ljvm $(MAC_OS_FLAGS) $^

test: lib/main target/simple/JavaCode.class
    lib/main

clean:
    -rm -rfv target/*
    -rm -rf lib/*
```

Then, you can call `make test`

```
llvm-g++ -c -o lib/main.o c/main.cc ...
...
...
lib/main
Status of JNI creation is : 0
JNI creation Passed :
The class of cls is : P7_jclass
The value of cls is : 0x7f895ec0d440
The value of mid is : 0x7f895ee11af0
Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!5|64|1000000
The value of square is 33
Result of implementation : 33
```

You can find lots of various JNI codes here: [JNI Cookbook](http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org)

**2. GNU based setup**

In case of GNU based setup (e.g. in Linux), you can truncate Makefile and remove Makefile.common.

```
CC=g++

all: lib/main target/simple/JavaCode.class

target/simple/JavaCode.class: java/simple/JavaCode.java
        $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac -cp ./jar/xeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -d target $<

lib/main.o: c/main.cc
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $^ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux

lib/main: lib/main.o
        $(CC) -v -o $@ -L${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -ljvm $^

test: lib/main target/simple/JavaCode.class
        lib/main

clean:
        -rm -rfv target/*
        -rm -rf lib/*
```

Of course, you have to make sure to download jars as well (into `jar` directory)

```
curl -O \
  "http://www.brics.dk/automaton/automaton.jar"
curl -O \ 
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/xeger/xeger-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

and simply call `make test`

```
make test
lib/main
Status of JNI creation is : 0
JNI creation Passed :
The class of cls is : P7_jclass
The value of cls is : 0x136b810
The value of mid is : 0x148fdc0
Hurrayyyyyyyy !!!!!!!!!!!!!!6|756293|1000000
The value of square is 33
Result of implementation : 33
```

Comment: What did you use to run it? did you use g++

Comment: Getting back after long time. I tried to run it in linux but I get llvm:command not found. Installed the llvm but still the problem remains.

Comment: Now there is a linker problem(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'. My JAVA_HOME is setup correctly and points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: make sure to have libjvm.so on ld_library_path when you run the code.

Comment: I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server but still the same problem

Comment: when I try to run it with this command :
g++ -g -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/ -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux/ -L/usr/bin/java -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server/ c/main.cc -o main -ljvm

then it generates the executable file. But when I use the make file then it gives me this error. My ignorance to create proper makefile must have something to do with it.

Comment: One comment! Make sure to use tabs as first characters in each makefile target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166356/discussion-between-enjal-parajuli-and-mko).